# How to save ISO datetime in MongoDB by Lua?

Tags: mongodb, datetime, lua

I want to save the datetime format as `ISODate("2013-10-09T13:19:10.962Z")` in MongoDB.

But when I use `lua-resty-mongol` I only manage to save it like `Wed Oct  9 17:28:03 2013`
which I retrieved from `os.date()` call.

Is there any ways I can do that in Lua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a workaround using Lua only facilities, if it is enough for you. Something on the lines:

```
print( os.date( "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S" ) )
```

See the [`os.date` docs](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-os.date).
and the [C `strftime` docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime).

Note that Lua `os.date` relies on the underlying `strftime` implementation, so the set of supported `%xxx` specifiers may vary.

Comment: You probably mean `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S`. This also works, but is less clear: `%FT%T`. You can add the time zone with `%z`.